# Action Script - мувиклип не виден на сцене

Tags: actionscript-3

Если останавливаю анимацию сразу после добавления на сцену, то мувиклип видно но слушатель не работает.
Если не останавливаю, то мувикли НЕ видно, но слушатель срабатывает и проигрывает анимацию. Правда срабатывает он правее координаты x

```
public class PlayScreen extends Sprite 
{
    var cell:MovieClip;
    var cellSize:int = 45;

    public function PlayScreen() 
    {
        super();
        cell = new Cell_mc();
        cell.width = 45;
        cell.height = 45;
        cell.x = 100;
        cell.y = 100;

        addChild(cell);

        cell.stop();
        cell.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onCellClick);
    }
    function onCellClick(e:Event):void
    {
        trace("Управление передается!");
        e.target.play();
        e.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onCellClick);

    }

}
```

Что за чертовщина творится???

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего, дело в самом мувиклипе, попробуй сделать новый мувик с простой анимацией и посмотри, остается ли проблема.

Еще может быть, что мувик у тебя объект класса SimpleButton, то есть при создании во флеше ты сделал его кнопкой (можно посмотреть в настройках мувика). Внутри он выглядит так:

[image]

В первом кадре лежит графика для обычного состояния, во втором для состояния когда на кнопку наведена мышь, в третьем для состояния когда на муыик нажимают и в четвертом лежит хитзона. Если в хитзоне что-то есть, то мышка будет реагировать (наведение, нажатие) только на область которая нарисована в этом кадре не зависимо от того, что нарисовано в первых трех кадрах. Это могло бы объяснить то, что мышка срабатывает правее координат мувика.

Если это не поможет, то надо больше информации, скрин мувика с его таймлайном, как делаешь эмбед мувика в код и так далее.